# JSon unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [

Tags: c#, json.net, shodan

Thanks in advance for the person who can help me with the issue below.
I am using the latest Newtonsoft.Json version from NuGet as of 2016.9.30
and this is the issue:

### Exception

`Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'matches[0].cpe', line 1, position 233.`

### using below class from Shodan.net(api for shodan)

```

````
[DataContract]
public class SearchHostResults
{
    [DataMember(Name = "matches")]
    public List<Banner> Matches { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "facets")]
    public Dictionary<string, Facet> Facets { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "total")]
    public int? Total { get; set; }
}


[DataContract]
public class Banner
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The timestamp for when the banner was fetched from the device in the UTC timezone.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "timestamp")]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Either "udp" or "tcp" to indicate which IP transport protocol was used to fetch the information
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "transport")]
    public string Transport { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// An array of strings containing all of the hostnames that have been assigned to the IP address for this device.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "hostnames")]
    public IList<string> Hostnames { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the organization that is assigned the IP space for this device.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "org")]
    public string Org { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "guid")]
    public string Guid { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Contains the banner information for the service.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "data")]
    public string Data { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The port number that the service is operating on
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "port")]
    public int Port { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The ISP that is providing the organization with the IP space for this device. Consider this the "parent" of the organization in terms of IP ownership.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "isp")]
    public string Isp { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The autonomous system number (ex. "AS4837"
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "asn")]
    public string Asn { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "location")]
    public Location Location { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The IP address of the host as an integer
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "ip")]
    public long? Ip { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The IPv6 address of the host as a string. If this is present then the "ip" and "ip_str" fields wont be.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "ipv6")]
    public string Ipv6 { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// ] An array of strings containing the top-level domains for the hostnames of the device. This is a utility property in case you want to filter by TLD instead of subdomain. It is smart enough to handle global TLDs with several dots in the domain (ex. "co.uk")
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "domains")]
    public IList<string> Domains { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The IP address of the host as a string
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "ip_str")]
    public string IpStr { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The operating system that powers the device.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "os")]
    public object Os { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Contains experimental and supplemental data for the service. This can include the SSL certificate, robots.txt and other raw information that hasn't yet been formalized into the Banner Specification.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "opts", IsRequired = false)]
    public dynamic Opts { get; set; }

    #region Optional Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// The number of minutes that the device has been online.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "uptime", IsRequired = false)]
    public int? Uptime { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "link", IsRequired = false)]
    public string Link { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "title", IsRequired = false)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "html", IsRequired = false)]
    public string Html { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "product", IsRequired = false)]
    public string Product { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "version", IsRequired = false)]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "devicetype", IsRequired = false)]
    public string DeviceType { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "info", IsRequired = false)]
    public string Info { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "cpe", IsRequired = false)]
    public string Cpe { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "ssl", IsRequired = false)]
    public SslProperties Ssl { get; set; }

    #endregion Optional Properties
}

```



```
[DataContract]
public class Facet
{
    [DataMember(Name = "count")]
    public int? Count { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
````

```

[Json code here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dMZ7IP7Q2Y1-wy8SrURgyPABNv3OkLoDHts2BPvB5Qs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you provide json message example?

Answer (score 2):

You have incorrect json format here:

```
"cpe": ["cpe:/a:pureftpd:pure-ftpd"],
```

You try to deserialize to string, but should deserialize it to string array.

```
[DataMember(Name = "cpe", IsRequired = false)]
public string[] Cpe { get; set; }
```